# How can I solve this CRUD set_relation_n_n issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have three tables:

```
aauth_user: id,email,pass,name,banned,last_login
aauth_user_to_groups: user_id,group_id
aauth_groups: id,name,definition
```

Here I want to set relation table  `auth_user_to_groups` with `auth_groups`.

Here `auth_user` is basic table and `auth_user_to_groups` is relational table and `auth_groups` is selection table

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM aauth_user_to_groups a
JOIN aauth_user b ON a.user_id = b.id
JOIN aauth_groups c ON a.group_id = c.id ;
```